# How do I fade/dim the background of my app while keeping a few in the front normal? For say, a notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Take this Tweetbot 3 screenshot:

[image]

How do I present a view and fade out ALL the back views except the one in front to a dark colour?

Comment: Add a view the size of the screen just behind the your front view, set it's background color to black with an alpha of 50% or so (e.g., `[UIColor colorWithRed:0.f green:0.f blue:0.f alpha:0.5f]`.

Comment: @bobnoble This was such a simple problem if OP just googled.

Comment: @mattcurtis The wording was hard to come up with, I Googled many times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a full screen UIView with background color as `[UIColor colorWithRed:0.f green:0.f blue:0.f alpha:0.5f]`and add your custom view as subView of this new view and then based on your needs you can present this new UIView on top of your current screen which will look faded out except for main centric view.